# It OK to use product list schema when only some of the products have detail pages and product schema markup?

Tags: schema.org, markup, categories, products

First and foremost, I'm creating a website for products which we have to hire. I cannot see a reason why I shouldn't use the Product structured data markup, unless anyone suggests otherwise?

Secondly, according to [Google's guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#multiple-elements-on-a-page):

> A category page listing several different products (or recipes,
>   videos, or any other type). Each entity should be marked up using the
>   relevant schema.org type, such as schema.org/Product for product
>   category pages. However, if one item is marked, all items should be
>   marked. Also, unless this is a carousel page, the marked items should
>   not link out to separate details pages.

On a category listing, some of my pages link out to specific product pages with further details. This is only true for about 50% of products due to the fact that many products don't need further information. I'm now just wondering what the best way to do structured data markup is. Should I just markup the products which have individual pages?

Is there actually any benefit to doing this at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the technically correct way to do this is to just mark up the URL if the product information is on another page, and mark up the Product if all the information is present on the page.